# Can I get an alternative browser (Firefox/Chrome) on Win8 RT?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, windows-rt

Where can I find Firefox or Chrome for Win8 RT?  I checked both google.com/chrome and firefox.com, but they seem to only have x86 version of the browser, but not ARM.

Comment: MS doesn't allow it. But there is a jailbreak tool: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2092158 to run unsigned desktop applications. Wait if someone ports the Firefox code to ARM.

Answer (score 16):

Neither is available as MS won't allow third-party apps full access to the system. This [blog post](http://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2012/05/09/windows-on-arm-users-need-browser-choice-too/) from Mozilla outlines their objections to this policy.

> It’s reported that Windows RT (the name Microsoft has given to Windows
>   running on the ARM processor)  will have two environments, a Windows
>   Classic environment and a Metro environment for apps. However, Windows
>   on ARM prohibits any browser except for Internet Explorer from running
>   in the privileged “Windows Classic” environment. In practice, this
>   means that only Internet Explorer will be able to perform many of the
>   advanced computing functions vital to modern browsers in terms of
>   speed, stability, and security to which users have grown accustomed.
>   Given that IE can run in Windows on ARM, there is no technical reason
>   to conclude other browsers can’t do the same.

[From Firefox](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/does-firefox-work-windows-8-and-windows-rt)

> Does Firefox work on Windows RT?
>
> Firefox is not available for Windows RT.

[From Google](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/06/try-chrome-in-metro-mode.html)

> (Chrome won’t run in WinRT, i.e. Windows 8 on ARM processors, as
>   Microsoft is not allowing browsers other than Internet Explorer on the
>   platform.)

Comment: This is not correct.  Firefox and Google have full access to the Windows RT API and have no need to use the desktop.

Comment: @Michael the OP was if there was an alternative browser available not could one be written. If you would like to provide an answer to that question please feel free to do so. As it stands my I feel my answer is not only correct but provide factual links to back up that.

Comment: In short, the Windows RT only supports applications written using Windows RT API and that prevents using `C/C++` programming languages. Unfortunately, any real world web browser is written in `C` or `C++`, including Microsoft Internet Explorer. Luckily for Microsoft, *they* can bend the rules and MSIE does work on Windows RT. In theory, some other browser written using only RT API could work but nobody is willing to create one (performance would suck and it would cost a fortune).

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen: It is my understanding that using C++/COM *is* possible in WinRT, and you can also make use of the Windows Runtime Library (WRL). See the "Don't care for the component extensions?" section of [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/262151/Visual-Cplusplus-and-WinRT-Metro-Some-fundamentals).

Comment: @Mikko: Hmm. There are two versions of IE on Windows RT - one is the desktop version that no-one uses, and there is a Windows RT one that goes through the RT api. So it's not a matter of closing an API for MS only.

Comment: @IsaacAbraham: Internet Explorer is not really an RT app. It's a "Metro style enabled desktop browser" and in non-RT Windows 8, there can be exactly *one* such application (your "default browser"). For Windows RT, there can be exactly *zero* such applications, unless the application is created and signed by microsoft. Source: http://www.brianbondy.com/blog/id/129/firefox-metro-development-begins-status-update and http://www.askvg.com/how-to-use-mozilla-firefox-metro-version-in-windows-8-fix-metro-app-launching-desktop-version/

Comment: @Mikko Rantalainen WinRT APIs do not prevent in any way using C/C++ programing languages. Amyuni PDF Creator for WinRT for example (a product I worked on) was implemented in C/C++.

Comment: @yms: Yeah, I currently believe that one can use C/C++ with Windows RT (WinRT API) as long as one uses toolchain by Microsoft to compile the code. And the interface between raw C/C++ and WinRT still does not look nice. However, WinRT APIs do not allow writing a JIT compiler for JavaScript, which is a requirement for decent performance on nowadays JavaScript heavy web sites; the missing part is the ability to create region of executable *and* writable memory. This is the same reason (in addition to political problems) preventing alternative browsers on iOS, too.

Answer (score 4):

There is no real technical reason or Windows Store rules preventing Google or Firefox from bringing their browser to Windows RT.  They have full access to the Windows RT API and have no reason to even need to access the desktop on Windows RT.

I also didn't hear Firefox or Google whine when they couldn't write a browser for iOS.

I really wish these browser companies would just stop whining about every choice Microsoft makes already.

Comment: Mozilla/Firefox did whine but it didn't help: http://venturebeat.com/2013/03/10/mozilla-firefox-ios/ - Google did, too, and in the end released "Chrome" for iOS but that's really only a UI wrapper for iOS webkit (the Safari variant by Apple).

Comment: The real technical reason is that VirtualAlloc function is not part of Windows RT API, and this function is vital for implementing JIT compiler. No JIT = slow JavaScript engine = unusable browser.

Comment: However somehow Microsoft is able to do it with Metro IE that runs under the same rules as everyone else.

Comment: @Michael care to point to *source* that claims that Metro IE plays under the same rules as everyone else?

Answer (score 1):

IE is the only browser to be provided access to the Desktop on Windows RT, and most probably as long as MS doesn't attain a monopoly in the market with WOA (Windows on ARM), [this state of affairs will continue](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2013097/eu-antitrust-regulators-let-microsoft-limit-browsers-on-windows-rt.html).

At this point it is unclear whether WinRT APIs *solely* without access to Desktop mode can enable creation of any other browser for WOA. Interestingly I did find [UC BrowserHD](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/uc-browserhd/3438cb63-1da0-4262-b204-175c3a748904) that can run on ARM and thus WinRT, but I don't know whether it's just a "skin" for the IE Trident engine (couldn't find details on [its site](http://www.ucweb.com/index.html)). I'll look into it further and perhaps try it myself, but if it's truly an independent browser for WinRT then that's quite an achievement and most likely the first of its kind.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason that there are no other browsers is that other browser companies would have to recreate both their browser's UI and their browser's engine, since they are not given permission to access the desktop, and also since C++ isn't compatible with WinRT. I personally find it really ironic that their less-powerful and less-popular Windows Phone 8 is compatible with the more advanced C++, however WinRT isn't.

Answer (score -1):

There is a browser called [UC browser](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/uc-browserhd/3438cb63-1da0-4262-b204-175c3a748904) that looks a lot like Firefox.  I think that it would be a good alternative for you.

Comment: Your link is dead.   Searching reveals a browser with the same name, but does not have anything to do with Microsoft.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UC_Browser   It appears to have questionable security practices and leaks data.